# How to configure POM.xml file to create JAR that would contain two different folders

Tags: maven, selenium, pom.xml

I am planning to run JAR file from command line to execute my selenium tests.
something like that:  "java selenium-0.0.1-snapshot.jar Test1.class" 
I am trying to configure POM file that at the build time will result in the JAR file, that would contain classes from 2 locations :
first location is a default - /src/main/java/test
second location - /src/test/java/test;
I was trying the following :

```
<groupId>com.imapdata</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>selenium</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
       <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>             
          </resource>
          <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/test/java</directory>        
          </resource>
        </resources> 
    ...
    </build>
```

that didn't work well.  If anybody can give me a clue on how to do that properly.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Will be executing my selenium tests not locally, but on a test server. Seems like its the company standard to create everything within pom. So they want it this way.  I'd need to run my tests via command line.    I know I could do it via Jenkins in its config as a post-build procedure, but was advised to run via command line;

Comment: Why do you have sources in 2 locations? Simply: src/main/java is something you deliver to world, src/test/java is something private-for-project